# How to create an empty kotlin job?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

There is a method that performs a network call. Sometimes I want to await for the result of that call, sometimes I don't. To achieve that behavior, I use `launch` method and return [Job](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/). So I can either `join` that job or not, depending on my needs. The problem is that sometimes I can be sure that network call is not required (request contains no data).

So how can I create an empty Job, that is already completed and doesn't disturb coroutine dispatcher? Naive `Job()` looks good enough, but probably I miss something important about internals of Kotlin coroutines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can simply create a job using `Job()` and complete it before returning:

```kotlin
fun doNetwork(): Job {
    val job = Job()
    job.complete()
    return job
}
```

We can also write it in a more concise way:

```kotlin
fun doNetwork(): Job = Job().also { it.complete() }
```